# exim - domainips config - how to use multiple ip's per domain

Tags: networking, email, exim

My domainips file:

```
officereflections.com: 185.65.105.57; 2a09:7c44:0:66::1;
executivebrand.info: 185.216.13.144; 185.216.13.145; 185.216.13.146;
*: 185.216.13.57;
```

Parts of exim.conf:

```
EXIM_DOMAINIPS = /etc/exim/domainips
interface = <;${lookup{$sender_address_domain}lsearch{EXIM_DOMAINIPS}}
```

Despite this config domain executivebrand.info still sending only from .144, ignoring 2 other addresses.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks Alex

I want my domains send mails from random IP's attached to them with /etc/exim/domainips

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It was clear:

I want my domains send mails from random IP's attached to them with /etc/exim/domainips - but now executivebrand.info sending only from 1st address in the list